# Point in java class

Tags: java, android, syntax

In Android I see a class named `SharedPreferences.Editor`, which provides an interface for data manipulation.

Now my question is: Why the class name has a name.name structure? What does it means?

Comment: Read the javadoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html It is listed as a nested class.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an inner class that in *not* bound to an instance of the outer class -- meaning that it can't access non-static members of the outer class, as there is no instance. This is used in cases where there is no need for an instance of the outer class, or if it isn't available.